# Forgot password error in Rails 4.2 with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I migrated my devise version from 1.4.9 to 4.2.0. In the sessions/new form, I am also using passwords/new in a modal. I am facing error when I run the sessions new form. Please help:

This is the error stack:

> ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0..1):
>   bartt-ssl_requirement (1.4.2) lib/url_for.rb:9:in
>   `url_for_with_secure_option'   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:280:in`call'   actionpack
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:223:in `call'
>
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:345:in`
>   block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/routes_proxy.rb:32:in `user_password_path'
>   devise (4.2.0) lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb:51:in`block (4
>   levels) in generate_helpers!'   app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:45:in
>   `_app_views_sessions_new_html_erb__3241459270597214406_43798180'
>
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in`block in
>   render'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'   actionview
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in`instrument'   actionview
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'   actionview
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in`block (2
>   levels) in render_template'   actionview (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in
>   instrument'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`block in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in`
>   instrument'   actionview (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
>
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in`
>   block in render_template'   actionview (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in
>   `render_with_layout'   actionview (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in`render_template' 
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in
>   `render'   actionview (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:46:in`render_template'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render'
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in`
>   _render_template'   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
>
>   actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in`render_to_body'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in
>   `render_to_body'   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in`render_to_body'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in`
>   render'   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels)
>   in render'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in`block in ms'
>   /home/osiuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
>   `realtime'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in`ms'   actionpack
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in
>   render'   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in`
>   cleanup_view_runtime'   activerecord (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in
>   `cleanup_view_runtime'   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in`render'
>   remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:14:in
>   `render_with_remotipart'   responders (2.2.0)
>   lib/action_controller/responder.rb:238:in`default_render'
>   responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:170:in `to_html'
>   responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:163:in`respond'
>   responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:156:in `call'
>
>   responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:205:in`
>   respond_with'   devise (4.2.0)
>   app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:12:in `new'

These are the lines I am facing error:

sessions/new (from line 45):

```
<%= semantic_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :remote => true, :format => :json, :html => { :id => 'password_reset' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
     <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Your email address', :input_html => { :placeholder => "Enter your email..."}%>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.buttons do %>
     <%= f.commit_button :label => 'Send me that link', :button_html => {:class => 'submit button'}%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

devise/session_controller:

```
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource)) #this is the line it's showing error.
  end
```

In my sessions controller, there is no new method, only create and redirect methods and I am not having passwords controller.

This is my routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions'}, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout" }
```

It is working in older version,so I didn't changed the routes. 
Please help

Comment: The error is coming from `bartt-ssl_requirement` gem; not `devise`. https://github.com/bartt/ssl_requirement says it is compatible only with `rails 3`; you are using rails version `4.2.6`. You might need to figure out how to replace or remove this gem.

Comment: What I am using in the Gemfile is fine as listed [here](https://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement/issues/7)